# Tomcat 7 automatic deploy with .bat

Tags: tomcat7

I'm trying to make use of a .bat file to do an automatic deployment on Apache Tomcat/7.0.70 with JVM Version 1.7.0_80-b15 and apache-ant-1.7.1.
However always when I run the .bat file without warning a continuous message appears

> deploy.war:
>   Target 'deploy.war' failed with message 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Fportal2CA&config=C%3A%2FTeste%2FAPRO%2Fportal2CA.xml&war=C%3A%2FTeste%2FAPRO%2Fportal2CA.war&update=true'.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Fportal2CA&config=C%3A%2FTeste%2FAPRO%2Fportal2CA.xml&war=C%3A%2FTeste%2FAPRO%2Fportal2CA.war&update=true

.bat

echo versao=1.01

REM ***** variable *****

SET APP-URL="http://localhost:8080/portal2CA"
SET MGR-URL="http://localhost:8080/manager"
SET MGR-USERNAME="XX"
SET MGR-PASSWORD="XX"
SET MGR-CONTEXT-PATH="/portal2CA"
SET MGR-WAR-FILE="C:/Teste/APRO/portal2CA.war"
SET MGR-CONTEXT-DESCRIPTOR="C:/Teste/APRO/portal2CA.xml"

call ant -v -k -f instalar.xml -Dapp.url=%APP-URL% -Dmgr.url=%MGR-URL% -Dmgr.username=%MGR-USERNAME% -Dmgr.password=%MGR-PASSWORD% -Dmgr.context.path=%MGR-CONTEXT-PATH% -Dmgr.war.file=%MGR-WAR-FILE% -Dmgr.context.descriptor=%MGR-CONTEXT-DESCRIPTOR%

pause

> OBS: Sorry for the parameters of Set em .bat, but i dont want show the names that enterprise using, but the path its correct, I want to know if something is missing in the .bat script.

.xml

(

```
<property name="versao"    value="1.02" />

<!-- Configure the custom Ant tasks for the Manager application -->
<taskdef name="deploy"    classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"    />
<taskdef name="list"      classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask"      />
<taskdef name="reload"    classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask"    />
<taskdef name="resources" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ResourcesTask" />
<taskdef name="roles"     classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.RolesTask"     />
<taskdef name="start"     classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask"     />
<taskdef name="stop"      classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask"      />
<taskdef name="undeploy"  classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask"  />


<target name="deploy.war">
    <deploy 

        url="${mgr.url}"
        username="${mgr.username}" 
        password="${mgr.password}" 
        update="true" 
        path="${mgr.context.path}" 
        localWar="${mgr.war.file}" 
        config="${mgr.context.descriptor}"
    />
</target>
```

)

Sorry for the bad editing, I still do not know how to tinker with the OS tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, there was only the need to in MRG-URL, at the end add a "/ text" and in tomcat.users.xml in roles, add a "manager-script"